# Why doesn't attempting to edit count as a pass for a review audit?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

I just got a question in the review queue that, though poor, I thought was potentially salvageable via editing.  However when I clicked the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button I got the deleted post error.  Since the post was gone, I clicked <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> (what is there do do with a deleted post?) only to get the review audit failed message instead.

The current behavior is also problematic in that, now that I know about it, it's a risk-free way to check if a question is an audit and not an actual review. That allows me or anyone else who knows about it to detect audits without having to recognize that the question is bad.

Comment: "what is there do do with a deleted post?" -- F5.

Comment: @JanDvorak don't you need to click I'm done/etc for the review to count?

Comment: This is probably a bug; at the very least getting a deleted post error by clicking Edit shouldn't activate the "I'm Done" button.

Comment: What? Unexpected behavior in the Review queue? STOP THE PRESSES!

Comment: @CodyGray Is this an indication that I'm not doing enough reviews?  :)

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217781/opening-the-post-editor-in-a-new-tab-does-not-pass-a-review-audit

Comment: Also possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169989/this-post-was-deleted-and-cannot-be-edited-on-audit

Comment: At least for the audit queues I have access to, I don't think that always holds, I often OPEN the question or answer myself in another tab to gain additional context and usually find them to be "old" questions.  That said I only have first post and late-answer rev queue's currently. But even trying to  edit them often passes the audit. This might relate here.

Comment: I always open in a new tab, and that doesn't pass the audit,  if you left click on the edit it passes, but not if you right click and open in a new tab, and I only do that because when I want to come back to the review it messes up sometimes, probably not much help.

Comment: @Laura One of the related questions linked to from mine should also be tagged as status-completed since it reported the same problem:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169989/this-post-was-deleted-and-cannot-be-edited-on-audit?lq=1  The second might be fixed too, but since that involved opening in a different tab I'm not sure if it was fixed too or not.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217781/opening-the-post-editor-in-a-new-tab-does-not-pass-a-review-audit?lq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed.  I got another one of these a minute ago.  I attempted to edit and got the message that I'd passed the review audit and displaying the question as closed.  When I clicked the link to show it outside of review I got the question deleted page.[image]

Comment: About time, huh?