# Opening the post editor in a new tab does not pass a review audit

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, editor

While reviewing late answers, I attempted to edit a poor answer by opening the editor in a new tab, and was faced with a notification that the post had been deleted.

If the post was deleted, the correct action is pretty clearly to do nothing, yet when I selected "No action needed" this message was returned:

[image: STOP! Look and Listen.]

Note that I *did* attempt to edit the post as suggested by this message, but was blocked from doing so while given no credit for trying.

Additionally, there is rogue semicolon at the end of this error message...

Comment: You passed! We occasionally insert rogue semicolons in site messages to make sure you're _really_ paying attention.

Comment: I'm confused here - were you actually able to open the editor? Clicking edit should have passed the audit immediately.

Comment: I was not able to open the editor. I clicked to edit and I got an empty page with just plain text stating that the answer no longer exists. Following that, I navigated back in the browser and clicked no action.

Comment: @Dan Then I think the error is that the message isn't loading properly. If it was a review audit, the post was *already* deleted. It wasn't deleted while you were reviewing.

Comment: Ah... Do you normally open the editor in a separate tab?

Comment: Honestly, I don't recall what I did in this particular instance. In general though, I would not open it in a new tab and I'm about 80% sure I didn't in this case. I do use tabs quite a bit though, so possible.

Comment: @animuson Sure. That doesn't really change the problem at hand though.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this is to open the editor in a separate tab (right-click the edit link, open in new tab or window). Unlike the inline editor, this fails to complete the audit (and will generate an error if you can't edit deleted posts).

Comment: @Shog9 That must be it then. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Related (about the semicolon): [Typo on the Close Votes review audit failure message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218456/223030)

Comment: @Shog9 I have noticed that sometimes when I try to edit posts from the review I am not brought back to review, and that I need to open in a new window.  maybe I should post that in meta next time I come upon that issue?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the trick. You are thinking "oh, it's already deleted, no **further** action is needed." But the audit is saying "pretend this exists and hasn't been deleted. What would the right action be?"

When you look outside the review queue and discover the post is deleted, that's a big clue that it's an audit, and that the right action would be to recommend deletion. I think flagging, closing, editing and commenting (from the review UI, not in your own tabs) will also pass the audit at that point. You are not shown items in the review queues that have already been deleted in any context other than an audit. Audits are pretending to show you real posts, but are in fact showing you non-real posts - deleted ones, or ones that have been faked up in some other way - and asking for your ruling on them if they were real.

Comment: Yes, I understand all of that. That doesn't make this any less of a bug. Me opening the editor in another tab should not behave differently than me opening it in the same tab. If that is impossible to implement, then it should be documented that new tabs cannot be used.

Comment: I don't think you do understand if it you clicked No Action Needed. That's what caused you to fail the audit. You can use the new tabs to gather information, but actions you take there can't be caught by the review counting and auditing mechanisms and I am not sure anyone expects that they should be.

Comment: I clicked no action because when I tried to take an action (Edit) it threw an error...

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me, except it was a "First Post" review, and I clicked the edit link within the review and the same things happened.  if that message is supposed to tell me that it was an audit it should just say so and tell me good job but we need you to down vote or whatever