# Typo on the Close Votes review audit failure message

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, spelling, wording

There is a (very minor) typo in the Close Votes review audit failure message. The message is presented as follows:

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. There are no major problems with this question. You should click Leave Open, or make minor corrections via Edit.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.;

The `;` at the end is a typo and is in the actual message that was displayed.

Comment: I just clicked "Close" by mistake on what turned out to be an audit, and I can confirm that the stray `;` is still there.

Comment: In case you get banned you can always argue that you wanted to verify this bug!

Comment: @rene Brilliant!

Comment: Believe this is present across all review queues - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225625/stray-semi-colon?lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You found our missing semicolon.  We misplaced this one during a rigorous game of who can spin the wheel of blame the fastest.  It will go out with the next build.

Comment: +1 You've got to keep some spares on hand. They tend to wander off...

Comment: Did you spin the wheel to determine whose fault it was? If so, do we get to play *Where's `;`* again?