# Stray semi-colon

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

So, I just failed an audit. Whole separate question about that to come, but unrelated - there seems to be a stray semi-colon at the end of the warning message.

This was the Late Answers Queue, on the very off chance the text comes from different sources.

[image]

Comment: Very much a duplicate - apologies.