# Extraneous semicolon on failed review audits

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

Doing some close vote reviews today, I came across an audit question that I (arguably) failed. While looking over the question, I noticed an extraneous semicolon in the "STOP!" box at the very end.

[image]

Comment: Been reported many times. Most recently: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225625/stray-semi-colon http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218456/typo-on-the-close-votes-review-audit-failure-message

Comment: I apologize. Doing a search for "audit review semicolon" resulted in nothing. But that's a little ridiculous that a one-character typographical error has been around long enough to merit two questions as far back as February 3rd.

Comment: I'll give them the benefit of the doubt that they've had much more important things to work on (see [this](http://moderator.stackexchange.com/2014/03/march-2014-newsletter/) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange) - both long suffered problems much more worthy of development effort than a typo, IMHO).