# Change Audit behaviour when pressing 'edit'

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

As outlined in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169989/this-post-was-deleted-and-cannot-be-edited-on-audit) bug report, when pressing edit on an audit, it goes to an odd page.

I would like to ask that this is changed because of the confusion it causes for new review users (Like me) and the fact that it is a giveaway that it is an audit for users who have reviewed for longer.

Personally, I just encountered this today, pressed the back button after the page, and as it was already deleted I pressed the 'pass' button, thinking it wouldn't matter as the post was 'deleted'. Of course I got told off by the system.

Please add a **continue** button to the page that will take you to the 'next' review. This would solve the confusion of new review users.